# Deployment with truffle fails

Tags: truffle

When deploying with truffle a contract on Ropsten, the deployment executes correctly. When deploying the same contract on FTM Testnet, this Error is issued:

```
Error: ETIMEDOUT
{
  "originalError": {
    "code": "ETIMEDOUT",
    "connect": true
  }
}
```

What could be the issue?

(All RPC and chain info are correctly written in the config)

Comment: Endpoint down? Does the account their have funds? Correct chainId :)?

Comment: @MajdTL This is all correct, and the endpoint isn't down.